# React presentational component unable to read value for <input /> from redux store using react container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm new to stackoverflow and quite new to using react/redux. I've been scanning over quite a few posts already to see if a similar post could provide me with an answer but I'm still left puzzled.

I currently have a presentational component "Repetitions" and a container component to get props from redux store and dispatch actions from the presentational component to redux store. I have the presentational component updating the redux store when I enter data into the input field but I am wanting to use the redux store to retrieve the input value so that when a user first comes on to the page the input value is "0" as that is the initial value inside the redux store.

I originally made a simple Counter component using react/redux and it was working ok. I have since made the "Repetition" component and altered the redux store to use a combinedreducer and this is when the problems seemed to start as neither components can read from the redux store.

**Rootreducer.ts**

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import countReducer from "./example/reducer";
import repetitionsReducer from "./reps/reducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    countReducer,
    repetitionsReducer
})

export default rootReducer;
```

**RepetitionsReducer.ts**

```
import { RepetitionsState } from "../types";
import { AddRepetitionsAction } from "./actions";

export type RepetitionsActionType = AddRepetitionsAction;

export type Dispatch = (action: RepetitionsActionType) => void;

// The reducer updates the count
const initialState: RepetitionsState = {
  repetitions: 0
};

const repetitionsReducer = (
  state = initialState,
  action: RepetitionsActionType
): RepetitionsState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_REPETITIONS":
      return { ...state, repetitions: action.repetitions };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default repetitionsReducer;
```

**RepetitionsContainer.ts**

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { RootState } from "../../store/types";
import { Dispatch } from "../../store/reps/reducer";
import { addRepetitions } from "../../store/reps/actions";
import Repetitions from "../../components/reps/Repetitions";

interface StateFromProps {
  repetitions: number ;
}

interface DispatchFromProps {
  updateRepetitions: (repetitions: number) => void;
}

export type RepetitionsProps = StateFromProps & DispatchFromProps;

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState): StateFromProps => ({
  repetitions: state.repetitions
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch): DispatchFromProps => ({
  updateRepetitions: (repetitions: number) => dispatch(addRepetitions(repetitions))
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Repetitions);
```

**RepetitionsComponent.ts**
**note:** When I try to console.log "repetitions" I am getting undefined at the moment.

```
import React from "react";
import { RepetitionsProps } from "../../containers/reps/Repetitions";

const Repetitions: React.FunctionComponent<RepetitionsProps> = ({ 
  repetitions, 
  updateRepetitions
}) => {
  console.log(repetitions)
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Reps</h3>
      <input
        onChange={(event) => updateRepetitions(Number(event.target.value))}
        value={ repetitions } // <-- This is the value i'm wanting to present to the user from the redux store
      />                         
    </div>
  );
};

export default Repetitions;
```

**App.ts**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import Header from "./components/header/Header";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import Counter from "./containers/example/Counter";
import Repetitions from "./containers/reps/Repetitions";
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import rootReducer from "./store/reducer";

const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools());

console.log(store.getState())

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header title={"Rep count"} />
      <Repetitions />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <Counter />
    </div>
  );
}


const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
);
```

The expected results I would be hoping to see would be a "0" presented in the input box underneath the "Reps" header when a user first loads the page. Instead the box is empty but the redux store shows the value for repetitions as "0".

[reps-input-desired-results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28NQu.png)

It is also worth noting that the counter below the input field used to read "0" from the redux store when I first loaded the page however now it is also undefined.

Thank you for taking the time to look at my post. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm... something is wrong here:

First of all, your state for repetition is currently holding an object. It should hold a simple number.

Secondly, the name of the repetition state on the store (from the snapshot you've attached) is "repetitionReducer" and not "repetition" as you try to fetch it in mapStateToProps:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState): StateFromProps => ({
  repetitions: state.repetitions // <- this one here...
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you Matti, your answer has got me 1 step closer! I modified the names of the combinedreducers so they match up with the reducers and now 
I'm getting [object Object] returned from the redux store in the input field when the page loads! I just need to find out why it's an object rather than a number. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ash I think that the first line of answer explains why: you have an object in that reducer instead of a number. Look at the initial state you are declaring.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks again for your help Matti!